# Validar campos com OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estou tentando chamar uma função *JavaScript* através do `OnClientClick`.

O problema é que ao rodar no navegador ele não valida os campos, é como se a função simplesmente não fosse chamada.

**JavaScript:**

```
function VerificaCampos() {
   //verifica processo    
   var ddlprocesso = document.getElementById("<%=ddlProcesso.ClientID%>")
   if (ddlempresa.options[ddlprocesso.selectedIndex].value == ""){
      alert("Favor preencher processo!");
      ddlprocesso.focus();
      return false;
```

**Botão:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" CssClass="botao" 
  Text="Gerar" OnClientClick="if(VerificaCampos()) return false;" 
  OnClick="btnBuscar_Click"/>
```

Comment: Você chegou a colocar um alert dentro da função para ver se ela é chamada?

Comment: Se a sua função estiver num arquivo `.js` não irá funcionar a parte do `asp.net`: `<%=ddlProcesso.ClientID%>`. Pode confirmar se está num arquivo ou na mesma página `.aspx`? Segundo, como o @CaiqueRomero comentou, validou se está entrando na function, usando um `alert` ou `console.log`?

Comment: @RobervalVenicio Conseguiu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos problemas é que em seu javascript você está instanciando o `ddlProcesso` e depois e depois tetando verificar outro objeto que não foi declarado o `ddlEmpresa`

```
function VerificaCampos() {
   //verifica processo    
   var ddlprocesso = document.getElementById("<%=ddlProcesso.ClientID%>")
   //if (ddlempresa.options[ddlprocesso.selectedIndex].value == ""){
   if (ddlprocesso.options[ddlprocesso.selectedIndex].value == ""){
      alert("Favor preencher processo!");
      ddlprocesso.focus();
      return false;
    }
}
```

Depois como o colega comentou, se o seu javascript estiver em arquivo js separado do aspx, o `Response.Write()` não irá funcionar, mas você pode contornar isso de maneira simples. Basta colocar em seu dropdown o atributo `ClientIDMode="Static"` assim seu id no DOM será "ddlProcesso" também

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProcesso" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
```

E no javascript você poderá selecioná-lo sem precisar da ajuda do ASP.Net

```
var ddlprocesso = document.getElementById("ddlProcesso");
```

E por último, mude o evento do seu botão, para `OnClientClick="return VerificaCampos();"`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" CssClass="botao" 
  Text="Gerar" OnClientClick="return VerificaCampos();" OnClick="btnBuscar_Click"/>
```